# Integration Testing - Mocking dependencies xUnit

Tags: mocking, xunit

When doing Integration testing ,without actually calling into a real database (in my case it is a Amazon DyanomoDb)
I want to show that the end to end test works fine.

So I am using WebApplicationFactory and starting a localhost instance then calling the relevant endpoints. but before that I am setting up the mocks and using a startup class just for my mocks to make sure the relevant instances are available

Do I mock only the interfaces or actual concrete classes of the Service layer ?
What I see is that If I just mock the Interfaces then only the API call Interfaces methods are executed but none of service layer Interfaces are executed.

I have an API endpoint (See below)
so the IDataWriter then calls another service IService that writes to a datastore.

I mock all the Interfaces, ILogger, IDataWriter and IService (that is used by the DataWriter.)
how evver when I execute the integration test, the API just return OK I can not get the Method in the IDataWriter to execute even though I set it up as a Mock with SetUp

```
public class TestController : Controller
        {
                private IDataWriter _dataWriter;
                private ILogger _logger;
        
                public TestController(IDataWriter  dataWriter,ILogger logger)
                {
                    _dataWriter = dataWriter;
                    _logger = logger;
                }
    
         public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] model)
         {
                _logger.Log("");
                _dataWrite.Write(model);
         }
    }
```

Mocking

```
public async task WhenDataWriterCalled_API_ReturnsOK
{
            var mockLogger = new Mock<IIlogger>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            var mockwriter = new Mock<IDataWriter>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            var mockService = new Mock<IService>(MockBehavoir.Strict);

            await using var appFactory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory(services =>
            {
                //Mock logger
                services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(_ =>
                {
                    
                    MockLogger.Setup(l => l.Log(It.IsAny<ModelWeb>()))
                    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask).Verifiable();
                    return MockLogger.Object;
                }));

                //mock dataWriter
                services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(_ =>
                {                    
                    mockWriter.Setup(w => w.Write(It.IsAny<DataServiceCore>()))
                    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask).Verifiable();
                    return mockWriter.Object;
                }));

                services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(_ =>
                {                   
                    mockService.Setup(r => r.AddUpdateData(It.IsAny<DataServiceCore>()))
                    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask).Verifiable();
                    return mockService.Object;
                }));
            });

            var _client = appFactory.CreateClient();
}

            //Act
            var request = new
            {
                Url = "http://localhost/api/Test/put",
                Body = new
                {
                    Id = "4b4a8e96a51d4ef1173766",
                    Version = "1.0.1",
                    FS = 98765432145
                }
            };

            var httpResponseMessage = await _client.PutAsync(request.Url, ContentHelper.GetStringContent(request.Body));

            httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, httpResponseMessage.StatusCode);
            mockwriter.Verify(w => w.Write(It.IsAny<DataServiceCore>()),Times.Once);
            mockLogger.Verify(l => l.Log(It.IsAny<ModelWeb>()), Times.Once );
            mockService.Verify(r => r.AddUpdateData<It.IsAny<DataServiceCore>()), Times.Once);

}
```

The issue I face is the the Method in the Service is never stepped into so the last assertion fails as the Service Layer method AddUPdateData is never executed in the test and yet the API Return a 200 Status OK.

So am I mocking the inner service correctly